# How to define an AJAX action?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I am creating a form that submits with AJAX then use $_POST to get the values of the form and enter them into the database. But I don't understand why I have had to define the action inside an input in my form, usually I would just define it inside my js. But if I do this I cannot access the $_POST data. Can someone please explain why this happens.

Here's my code that works;

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#add_event_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var form_data = form.serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            data: form_data,
            error : function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            success : function(response){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**php**

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_event', 'add_event');
    add_action('wp_ajax_add_event', 'add_event');

    function add_event(){
        global $current_user;
        global $wpdb;
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;

        $event_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['event_name']);

        $wpdb->insert('wp_events', array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'event_name' => $event_name,
        ) ); 

        die(); 
    }
?>
```

**html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="add_event_form">
    <h3>ADD EVENT</h3>

    <div class="form_row">
        <label>Event Name
            <input type="text" name="event_name" class="event_name required">
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_event">
</form>
```

And heres how I would usually define my action, why does this not work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#add_event_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var form_data = form.serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            // data: form_data,
            data: { 
                action: 'add_event',
                data: form_data,  
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            error : function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            success : function(response){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

This isn't finished so please excuse any security issues etc.

Comment: I just wanted to say when using `$wpdb->insert()` you shouldn't escape the values. `$event_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['event_name']);` should just be `$event_name = $_POST['event_name'];` or better `$event_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'event_name');`

Read up: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row

Comment: @Kevin Thanks I will look into that

Comment: What's not working? The action or the post data? You have to do `$_POST['data']['event_name']`;

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the browser sends all data (eg. through the browser's network console)? Have you checked which data reaches the server (eg. through dumping `$_POST`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript you have `data: form_data` which is an array that contains objects like this `{name: "event_name", value: "test"}`. Which will result in this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: ajax_url,
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'add_event',
    data: [{name: "event_name", value: "test"}]
  }
});
```

This wont work.

---

The `data` property of jQuery's ajax should contain key-value pairs, like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: ajax_url,
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'add_event',
    event_name: 'test'
  }
});
```

---

Edit: if you don't want to change your javascript code you could also get the data in PHP by using:

```php
$data = $_POST['data']; // the 'data' array from jQuery's ajax call
$event_name = $data['event_name'];
```

However, I woulnd't recommend doing it in this way.